# Controller specific manifests in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, sprockets

**Rails 4**

**How can I include/exclude manifests based on their controllers?**

I have application.css - which includes global assets used by all layouts.

In addition, I have a frontend.css and a dashboard.css

I would like `application.html.erb` to **include** `application.css` *and* `frontend.css`, but **exclude** dashboard.css

I would like dashboard.html.erb to **include** `application.css` *and* `dashboard.css`, but **exclude** `frontend.css`

How should I structure my assets, and what should the layout files and manifests look like?

Answer (score 0):

I would do this:

```
#app/views/layouts/application.html.erb
<%= stylesheet_include_tag "application", media: "all", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
<%= stylesheet_include_tag type, media: "all", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>

#app/helpers/application_helper.rb
def type
   controller_name == "dashboard" ? "dashboard" : "frontend"
end
```

---

```
#app/assets/stylesheets/application.css
/* global manifest -- fonts etc */

#app/assets/stylesheets/dashboard.css
/* dashboard specific */

#app/assets/stylesheets/frontend.css
/* frontend specific */
```

Basically, I would put some logic in the layout, which could be condensed to a helper, to determine which controller / conditions are valid to load up `dashboard.css` / `frontend.css`

Hope this helps?